# Batch UPDATE not working

Tags: google-api, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

We are updating multiple cells using batch UPDATE in Google Spreadsheets. In the recent days, we see that some rows are not updated for some of our users for a a few days and then works normally. I will explain the use-case exactly.

For example, in a sheet, content would get added upto 71 rows(this can be any number. 71 is used as an example) by Google Sheets batch update and we try updating 72nd row but it doesn't update and we do not get any exception. 72nd row will be empty and this won't get updated even if we try multiple times. But, it will work if we try to add some content above 73rd row. It may again fail somewhere in 156th row (randomly). After a few days if we try to add content in 72nd row it would work normally.

Please help us troubleshoot this issue. This is the code we are using,

```
// Prepare the update
CellFeed batchRequest = new CellFeed();
    for (CellInfo cellAddr : cellAddrs) {
         CellEntry batchEntry = new CellEntry(cellAddr.row, cellAddr.col, cellAddr.idString);
          batchEntry.setId(String.format("%s/%s", worksheet.getCellFeedUrl().toString(), cellAddr.idString));         
          BatchUtils.setBatchId(batchEntry, cellAddr.idString);
          BatchUtils.setBatchOperationType(batchEntry, BatchOperationType.UPDATE);  
          batchRequest.getEntries().add(batchEntry);

    }
// Submit the update
CellFeed cellfeed = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);
    Link batchLink = cellfeed.getLink(Link.Rel.FEED_BATCH, Link.Type.ATOM);
    URL batchUrl = new URL(batchLink.getHref());
    service.setHeader("If-Match", "*");
    CellFeed batchResponse = service.batch(batchUrl, batchRequest);
    service.setHeader("If-Match", "*");
```

Comment: Please post your code. Its hard to understand the reason why some rows are not updated.

Comment: I have added here the code snippet and the explanation of usecase.

Comment: You might want to open an issue with google. Large sheets tend to cause problems, so you could try splitting into smaller sheets. But my first guess would be the data, are you sure there is nothing strange about the data you are writing. Also I do get errors with the API, maybe 1 in 50 writes will fail, so I have a re-try (but I get a time out error, so sounds different)